# Animation callback calling at wrong time

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to make a bounce effect on my custom scroller. (I'm scrolling using `translate3d`.) I was finally able to implement it, but the only problem now is, if you keep on scrolling out of bounds (try double scrolling and just keep doing it till it gets stuck), then it will stay out of bounds until you scroll back down (or up, depending on where it's stuck).

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPZGk.jpg (for some reason, stackoverflow isn't letting me to add the gif.) code: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/092f6byb/)

### Question:

How can I make a scrolling bounce effect using JavaScript and CSS?

**The rest is optional to read.**

### Reason why not working:

I think the reason it's doing that is: there's an animation callback event. So if the animation doesn't happen, i.e., the transform doesn't change, then the animation callback will not fire.

So when it's scrolled all the way to the top or bottom, and you scroll again, (before the animation completes, so the animation callback doesn't get called, because the transform value didn't change) the animation callback will not get called, and therefore it won't scroll (bounce) back to bounds.

### What I tried:

I tried checking to see if the scroll position changed, and if it didn't call the animation callback function, but it doesn't give the desired results. When you try scrolling out of bounds a lot at a time, it gives a 'stuttering' effect, and doesn't scroll all the way out of bounds, it stops midway and scrolls back. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noIOE.jpg [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dy863o3x/)

I also tried changing the transform value by 0.1 whenever the scrolling position didn't change, therefore the animation callback will get called. The problem with that is, if you scroll out of bounds, it waits a a half a second to bounce back.
So I set the animation duration to a shorter time when the scrolling position didn't change, but if you scroll repeatedly out of bounds, i.e., you keep on scrolling when it's out of bounds, up or down, then it waits a second, then bounces back. [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ve5yjxkL/)

```js
console.clear();

var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
var scrollBar = document.getElementById('scrollbar');
var scrollBarThumb = scrollBar.firstElementChild;

var scrollPosition = 0;
var scrolledToBottom = innerWrapper.scrollHeight - innerWrapper.parentElement.offsetHeight;

scrollBarThumb.style.height = (innerWrapper.offsetHeight * innerWrapper.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.scrollHeight) + 'px';

innerWrapper.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleScroll);
innerWrapper.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', handleScroll);
innerWrapper.addEventListener('transitionend', bounceBack);

innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';

function handleScroll(e) {
  // Prevent parents from scrolling
  e.preventDefault();
  var direction = (e.detail < 0 || e.wheelDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1; // 1 = scroll down, -1 = scroll

  scrollPosition += direction * 100; // Cannot use `deltaY`, because not all browsers support it.
  scrollPosition = clamp(scrollPosition, -scrolledToBottom - 40, 40); // 40 = bounce amount

  var scrollThumbPosition = (scrollPosition * scrollBarThumb.offsetHeight / innerWrapper.parentElement.offsetHeight);
  scrollThumbPosition = clamp(scrollThumbPosition, -scrolledToBottom, 0);

  innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + scrollPosition + 'px, 0px)';
  scrollBarThumb.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + -scrollThumbPosition + 'px, 0px)';
}

function bounceBack(e) {
  // Scrolling stopped too high?
  if (scrollPosition > 0) {
    scrollPosition = 0;
    // Scrolling stopped too low?
  } else if (scrollPosition < -scrolledToBottom) {
    scrollPosition = -scrolledToBottom;
    // Scrolling stopped in viewport (i.e. not out of bounds)?
  } else {
    return;
  }

  // Bounce back with shorter animation
  innerWrapper.style.transitionDuration = '100ms';
  innerWrapper.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (scrollPosition) + 'px, 0px)';


  // Need a 'pause' for the transform to finish with shorter animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Set animation time back to original
    innerWrapper.style.transitionDuration = '500ms';
  });
}

function clamp(val, min, max) {
  if (typeof min !== 'number') min = 0;
  if (typeof max !== 'number') max = 1;
  return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
}
```

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
}
#innerWrapper {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#content {
  background-image: url("http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/previews/3037/30376024-beautiful-flower-portrait.jpg");
  width: 400px;
}
#scrollbar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#scrollbar_thumb {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
      sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus
      Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus
      enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar
      justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames
      ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque
      Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem
      lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie
      vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum
      vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque
      Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci
      Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla.
      Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet
      risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat
      Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor
      dolor
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scrollbar">
    <div id="scrollbar_thumb"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You realize if not using a wheel, nothing is even scrollable, right?

Comment: @Scott Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, I do plan on fixing that after I get the basic functionality finished with. (i.e. the scrolling and bouncing.)

Comment: @Scott Can you please try to answer it? I've been working on it the whole day, without success.

Comment: Just an option. You can use animate.css so it will be easier. You will just add/remove class all the time. https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 1):

I might use the z component to make a subtle difference between each wheel event in order to trigger transition. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/rd2bx929/)

```
var i = 0;
// onmousewheel
.. el.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 40px, ${i^=1}px)` 

// ontransitionend
.. el.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0, -1px)`
```

---

If the above approach is too tricky, we may do an expensive query to find what the current translation y is. Then compare it to the bounceAmount(e.g. 40 in your case), if they are almost identical(diff. < Number.EPSILON) then call `bounceBack()` directly.

```
var m = getComputedStyle(el).transform.match(/,\s*([^,]*?)\s*\)/)
m ? m[1] : 0 // current translation y
```

---

Update

If the content is required to be bounce back instantly, we can simply disable `onwheel` when motion starts, then re-enable it after whole motion has completed. This does not require the z component trick anymore. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/rd2bx929/2/)

Comment: What does `z^=1` do?

Comment: I've never seen `^` in javascript... can you link an article about it? Also, I tried it, and the problem is, it waits a 500ms before bouncing back. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/euqbyaph/ change is at line 29

Comment: No. it waits 500ms, then bounces back

Comment: I modified your fiddle a little bit so that there is no wait before bouncing back. https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/euqbyaph/1/

Comment: That part works fine, but regular scrolling is now choppy. (I edited your version a bit to make regular scrolling work) https://jsfiddle.net/sr05bj6L/

Comment: The fiddle based on yours is an approach for "no-stuck-on-double-scroll", it is intended to be choppy if blindly disable `onwheel`. The updated ans. has shown that `onwheel` should be disabled during bouncing fx and not for normal scroll